# A Docker IMAP server for repeat-testing INBOUND email? Reverse mailhog?

Tags: docker, imap, sendmail

*Woo-hoo!*  Thanks that we have `mailhog` for reliable Docker-based testing environments for *outbound* mail ... allowing us to easily debug mail-sending services without bothering production users ...

... but what about *inbound* emails?

On one of our sites, users can send an email to a designated support-address and their email will automagically be entered into a ticket system.  *(As you can well imagine, I am now tasked with replacing that system.)*  So, is(n't) there already a sort of "reverse mailhog" system, which would allow me to define an "incoming-mail server" which I could from time to time say "had just received thus-and-so message?"

Since this now seems to me to be "just as obvious a requirement as the one 'mailhog' so adroitly solved," I now ask the community – am I overlooking something wonderful that I literally don't yet know about?  (Pretty-please tell me in your reply that the answer is 'yes.')